# Import Posts from Wordpress Blog with thumbnail

Tags: php, json, wordpress, post, import

I am looking for php script to import posts from wordpress blog and show it on my other website with a thumbnail of the blog post.. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has an included feature called `Press this`. On your Wordpress admin pannel, tools tab you can drag `Press this`to your bookmarks. Then if you want to import a post from another site, go to the post page and click the bookmark. A popup will pop and you can easely import it.